# How does Mathematica's B-Spline NURBS work?

Tags: interpolation, splines

I'm finding that Mathematica is getting hung up on a numerical integration and I suspect I can do it faster myself in C++. I can scoop the control points of the BSplineFunction out of the interpolation. But I'm having problems figuring out the basis functions at the endpoints. I get the `BSplineFunction[]` is a particular implementation of `Sum[pts*BSplineBasis[{d,knots},i,x],{i,1,n}]`. At this point, I just need to know what Mathematica's default knots are so I can do a `PiecewiseExpand[BSplineBasis]`.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. You can take the site [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how to write a better question. At present, you have not included a **minimal working example** that forum participants can experiment with by replicating the challenges you face in their own Mathematica environments. Until this happens, your question will not receive much traction.

Comment: [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FullBSplineCurve/) is a function that explicits the defaults setting of `BSplineCurve[]`

Comment: The first entry in details on https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplineKnots.html tells which knots are used